# iPhone: Using Instruments to detect current memory usage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode-instruments

I am using Instruments to track memory for my app. I see it gives me a count of the # of allocated pages. However, I hear this number almost always increases and isn't a true count of the current amount of memory used. Is there a true count of the amount of current memory my app is using in Instruments?

I'm using Xcode 4 and looking at Instruments for iOS memory

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using, and what specific instrument?

Comment: Xcode 4. Umm.. Instruments for iOS Memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instruments -> allocations

in the same row as * All Allocations *, look for the data under "live bytes"

that's the current amount of memory used.